# winRT XAML Toolkit Data Visualization Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I try to implement WinRT XAML Toolkit Data Visualization
I have a Grouped List of Data

```
 ObservableCollection<Notes> items = await App.DataModel.GetNotes();

        var groupedData = (from data in items
                           group data by data.Title into g
                           orderby g.Key
                           select new Group<string, Notes>
                           {
                               Key = g.Key.ToString(),
                               Items = g.ToList()
                           }).ToList();

        List<GroupedDataType> groupedList2 = new List<GroupedDataType>();

        foreach (var item in groupedData)
        {
            int results = 0;
            foreach (var rslt in item.Items)
            {
                results += rslt.Result;
            }

            groupedList2.Add(new GroupedDataType(results, item.Items[0].Title));
        }
        PieChart.ItemsSource= groupedList2;
```

The Class:

```
 public GroupedDataType(int totalresult, string type)
    {
        TotalResult = totalresult;
        Type = type;
    }

    public int TotalResult { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
```

The XAML Code :

```
 <Charting:PieSeries x:Name="PieChart"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Type}"
                     DependentValueBinding="{Binding TotalResult}">
                </Charting:PieSeries>
```

But it doesn't show any chart, please help me know if I did something wrong with my code,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with PieCharts, but in general you bind to a collection `ItemsSource="{Binding groupedList2}"`

```
<Charting:Chart x:Name="MyPie" Title="Results" Width="400" > 
        <Charting:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding groupedList2}" IndependentValuePath="Type"
            DependentValuePath="TotalResult"> 
        </Charting:PieSeries> 
</Charting:Chart>
```

Something like this.

And if you change the binding as you did in: *(which I would remove since you are going to bind from the start and you are using an observable collection)*

```
PieChart.ItemsSource= groupedList2;
```

You should implement a [notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx) to the xaml to tell it to re-render.

```
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Again, I haven't worked with Pie Charts

Comment: Hello Barn, thanks for your help

<Charting:Chart x:Name="PieChart" >
                        <Charting:PieSeries IndependentValuePath="Type" 
        Title="Points"
DependentValuePath="TotalResult">
                        </Charting:PieSeries>
                    </Charting:Chart>


I try to implement this, it works while debugging but when I release I cant navigate to that page, it said that : pieseries cannot be added to a collection/dictionary of type collection1